# How to create class diagram of single class that is not using inheritance using Doxygen Graphviz?

Tags: doxygen, class-diagram, doxygen-wizard, doxywizard, doxygen-addtogroup

I have evaluated Doxygen. I found that a class which is inheriting property from another class, that class diagram is generated by Doxygen.
But for single class that  is not using  inheritance, Doxygen is not  generating class diagram of that class.
So how to resolve this.

I have added Graphviz path.
I have marked all Graphviz diagram.
Marked all required field like
HAVE_DOT=YES
UML_LOOK=YES
etc.....

My expectation is
Doxygen should be able to generate class diagram of all type of class.

Comment: Which version of doxygen you used? Please add a small example of a class with and one without inheritance to the question and also the doxygen settings used that differ from the default (i.e. the result of `doxygen -x Doxyfile) so in discussions we are always talking about the same.

Comment: Sir, I am using 1.9.8 version of Doxygen. And I only want class diagram which contain all the attribute and function present in class. I am getting it using COLLABORATION_GRAPH but the structure it is giving is not consumable. I only want a single class diagram.

Answer (score 0):

I quickly made an example (hopefully this is like OP wants it),and used the current 1.9.8 doxygen version:

**aa.h**

```
class no_inher
{
  public:
    int i;
};

class base_inher
{
  public:
    int i;
};

class derived_inher : public base_inher
{
  public:
    int j;
};
```

**Doxyfile**

```
QUIET = YES
HAVE_DOT = YES
UML_LOOK = YES
EXTRACT_ALL = YES
#COLLABORATION_GRAPH = NO
```

**Result with inheritance**

[image]

**Result without inheritance**

[image]

Might have been that OP set `COLLABORATION_GRAPH = NO` instead of (the default) `COLLABORATION_GRAPH = YES`

Comment: Sir, I am using 1.9.8 version of Doxygen. And I only want class diagram which contain all the attribute and function present in class. I am getting it using COLLABORATION_GRAPH but the structure it is giving is not consumable. I only want a single class diagram

Comment: What do you mean with "he structure it is giving is not consumable."? With the current master (1.10.0 (f23bba320bdc04996849bd8a369414f4a7950a0d)) there are some more possibilities as there we have a command `\hideinheritancegraph`.

Answer (score 0):

As written in the comment with the current master version of doxygen (1.10.0 (f23bba320bdc04996849bd8a369414f4a7950a0d)) there are some more possibilities as there we have a command \hideinheritancegraph

I quickly made an example,and using the current master version ofdoxygen version:

**aa.h**

```
class no_inher
{
  public:
    int i;
};

/// \hideinheritancegraph
class base_inher
{
  public:
    int i;
};

/// \hideinheritancegraph
class derived_inher : public base_inher
{
  public:
    int j;
};
```

**Doxyfile**

```
QUIET = YES
HAVE_DOT = YES
UML_LOOK = YES
EXTRACT_ALL = YES
#COLLABORATION_GRAPH = NO
```

**Result with inheritance base**

[image]

**Result with inheritance derived**

[image]

**Result without inheritance**

[image]